# TearDown always falls in RemoteDriver if test fails before

Tags: selenium, driver, selenoid

If my test fails and a session on RemoteDriver ends before or element is not founded and the session on selenoid(RemoteDriver) ends my tearDown fails too. How can I check current session if it not fail and I can use driver.quit() and how I can avoid this error when session end before tearDown.

[image: log error]

[image: BeforeAfter config]

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means you did not interact with browser more that specified with `-timeout` parameter (default is 1 minute) or `sessionTimeout` capability. Either check why you are having such long pauses between subsequent Selenium requests or increase timeout value e.g. to 2 minutes.

Comment: got it. The site which I am testing was not working at that moment and that's why the pause was so long. Now it works fine. Thanks for your reply.